# How concatenate variable into a string query with t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I do not understand why my request does not appear with the print and suddenly, that it does not execute. For your information, @month returns one value '202205'.

my t-sql code :

```
use rh_usc

declare @month as varchar(100)
declare @query as varchar(max)

set @month += @month(select [Affichage période (AAAAMM)] from employees)
print @month

if object_id('employees_202205') is not null drop table [dbo.employees_202205]

set @query = 'select * into [employees_' + @month + '] from [employees]'
print @query
exec(@query)
```

Could you please help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

In this example, @month will actually be NULL since you don't initialize it when you declare it, nor do you account for NULL in the concatenation.  Concatenating anything with NULL will return NULL.

```
DECLARE @month AS VARCHAR(100);
SET @month += @month + (SELECT [Affichage période (AAAAMM)] from employees);
PRINT @month;
```

Since @month is NULL to start, this concatenation will yield NULL and the print statement won't output anything.

If you change the first line to

`declare @month as varchar(100) = '';`

then you should get a result, assuming there is a value in the table.

Better yet, account for a NULL value in the code.  [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) checks for NULL values.

```
DECLARE @month AS VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @month = CONCAT(@month, (SELECT [Affichage période (AAAAMM)] FROM employees));
PRINT @month;

IF OBJECT_ID('employees_202205') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo.employees_202205];

SET @query = 'select * into [employees_' + ISNULL(@month, '') + '] from [employees]';
PRINT @query;
EXEC (@query);
```

Note: In the above examples I also fixed a syntax error in your code in the first SET statement

`SET @month += @month(SELECT [Affichage période (AAAAMM)] FROM employees)`

will set @month and then execute a SELECT as an individual statement.

Comment: my print commande returns now : select * into [employees_] from [employees]

Comment: Look at my full example that accounts for a NULL value for @month and also fixes the syntax error in your code.

Comment: Yet when I run the command SELECT distinct [Display period (YYYYMM)] FROM employees, the result tells me 202205

Comment: If you ran the code I posted it shouldn't have.  I did update it again because using CONCAT is a better way to do it.

Comment: Is this the full code you're working with though?  Because, really, you don't need to concatenate @month at all in your example.  You could just use `SET @month = ISNULL((SELECT [Affichage période (AAAAMM)] FROM employees), '');`  If this is a snippet from a bigger block of code and you initialize @month earlier then CONCAT is what to use.

Comment: it now works correctly. I added the DISTINCT command to the line set SET @month = CONCAT(@month, (SELECT DISTINCT [Display period (YYYYMM)] FROM employees));

Comment: Ah, good.  Actually, I imagine it would be better to use a WHERE clause in that query instead of DISTINCT.  Using DISTINCT means that _every_ value in the table for that column is the same.  That's rarely the case.

Comment: This is the case for me. The final idea is to create as many tables as there are dates. For example if I have 50 rows with date 202205 and 100 rows with 202206 then I would like to create 2 different tables filled with the 50 and 100 rows

Comment: `SET @month = CONCAT(@month,` is a bad idea, it has undefined behaviour. Use `STRING_AGG` instead

Comment: @Charlieface Hmm, what causes the undefined behavior?  I've never had a problem with it.  Is it because of setting the variable while reading the value of the variable?

Comment: it's dependent on execution plan. If you add an `ORDER BY` for example then it will completely mess up, as the right side is only calculated once. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709/220697 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Wasn't aware of that, thanks for pointing it out.